How test code in event listener of useRef
My react project consumes a 3rd party SDK that calls a number of events. How can I trigger the events using react testing library?
const el = React.useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  el.current.addEventListener('fatalError', () => {
    // code I'm trying to test
...

return (
  <third-party-component ref={el}

